# Manipulate: does not respond to the function I intend to plot

Tags: equation-solving, functions, manipulate

Please have a look at below. I need to solve two-coupled equations and plot the results `h[2]` and `theta[2]`. I am not sure about the function definition for `p01` and `p02` which use x as a variable not `h[2]` and `theta[2]`. Then I put these `p01, p02` inside `first, second,` etc which use `h[2]` and `theta[2]` as argument. I guess that part cause the problem for manipulate..

```
p01[x_] := 2*h[2]/k*Log[(x - b)/(-b)] + theta[2]/k*x + 1/2;

p02[x_] := 2*h[2]/k*Log[(x - b)/(1 - b)] + theta[2]/k*(x - 1); 

first[h[2] _, theta[2] _] := Integrate[p01[x], {x, 0, b}, Assumptions -> 0 < b < 1]

second[h[2] _, theta[2] _] := Integrate[p02[x], {x, b, 1}, Assumptions -> 0 < b < 1]

third[h[2] _, theta[2] _] := Integrate[(x - b)*p01[x], {x, 0, b}, Assumptions -> 0 < b < 1]

fourth[h[2] _, theta[2] _] := Integrate[(x - b)*p02[x], {x, b, 1}, Assumptions -> 0 < b < 1]

Solve[2*M*h[2] == first[h[2] _, theta[2] _] + second[h[2] _, theta[2] _] - 
M*g && 2*M*gamma*theta[2] == third[h[2] _, theta[2] _] + fourth[h[2] _, 
theta[2] _], {h[2], theta[2]}]

h[0] = k*b*(1 - b);
theta[0] = k*(1 - 2*b);
height[t_] := h[0] + t^2*h[2];
angle[t_] := theta[0] + t^2*theta[2];

Manipulate[
Plot[ h[0] + t^2*h[2], {t, 0, 0.1}, Filling -> filling, 
PlotRange -> {0.232, 0.245}], {M, {None, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0}}, {M, 
0, 1}, {g, {None, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.1, 0}}, {g, 0, 10},
{b, {None, 1, 0.6, 0.5, 0.3, 0}}, {b, 0, 1},
{gamma, {None, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0}}, {gamma, 0, 1},
{k, {None, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0}}, {k, 0, 1},
{filling, {None, 2, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 
0, -0.5, -1, -1.5, -2}}, {filling, -2, 2}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as you ran into in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128512/manipulate-is-not-working). Did you read the linked duplicate? `Manipulate` scopes its variables, so you have to tell *Manipulate* that those variables are there, either with the replacement rule trick explained by @feyre, or by redefining your functions to include the variables, i.e. `h[2, M_, g_] := ... ` rather than `h[2, M, g]`.

Comment: Thanks @march, I see what you mean. However, I have lots of parameters that the plot needs to be manipulated with, namely `M, g, b, gamma, k`.  As I used `height[t_,  kappa_, b_, M_, g_, gamma_] inside `Manipulate`, I have below code:
`Manipulate[
 Plot[ height[t_,  \[Kappa]_, b_, M_, g_, \[CapitalGamma]_], {t, 0, 
   0.1}, Filling -> filling, 
  PlotRange -> .....`   However, I do not have any luck..